# How to get the default value of an optional parameter julia?

Tags: reflection, julia

It is possible to get the values from a struct by using getproperty.
I am interested in the same thing but for optional/default arguments.

How would I proceed to achieve this in Julia?

```
function foo(a,b,c=1)
...
end
getDefaultArg(foo, c)
=> (c, 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `foo(a,b,c=42) = a*b*c`, Julia just defines two methods:

```
foo(a, b) = foo(a, b, 42)
foo(a, b, c) = a*b*c
```

You can see this just by asking Julia for the methods:

```
julia> foo(a, b, c=42) = a*b*c
foo (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> methods(foo)
# 2 methods for generic function "foo":
[1] foo(a, b) in Main at REPL[120]:1
[2] foo(a, b, c) in Main at REPL[120]:1
```

That's all an optional (positional) parameter does.  In fact, there are times where you want the optional parameter to come at the first argument, but that's not a supported syntax.  So instead you can manually do something like:

```
print(x) = print(stdout, x)
print(io, x) = # actually print to the io
```

In that manner, `io` is just as "optional" of an argument as `c` was in your example.  Of course, I hope you can see how this makes the reflection here, well, rather tricky.  One potential avenue would be to ask what the two-argument `foo` does:

```
julia> code_lowered(foo, Tuple{Any,Any})
1-element Array{Core.CodeInfo,1}:
 CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = (#self#)(a, b, 42)
└──      return %1
)
```

So a potential "reflection-like" utility could be build to introspect on this IR:

```
julia> c = code_lowered(foo, Tuple{Any,Any})
1-element Array{Core.CodeInfo,1}:
 CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = (#self#)(a, b, 42)
└──      return %1
)

julia> c[1].code[1].args[end]
42
```

Of course, you'd want to bundle this up into a function with copious amounts of error checking to make sure that the method really is just calling itself with nothing else happening besides filling in that last argument.

Comment: Perfect! The much of the other scaffolding is already in place for my use case :) 
I get this back: :((_1)(_2, _3, 42)), is it safe to asume all _1 arguments are user supplied?

Comment: Those `_N` names are called slots.  You can see what their names are with `c[1].slotnames`, and you'll quickly discover that `_1` is the function itself and then `_2` and `_3` are the first two arguments.